# convert BIGINT to HEX in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have `BIGINT` number example 1234567891 the hex of this number is 0x499602D3.
I want to know how this conversion can done in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: possible duplicate of [decimal to hex conversion in sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643729/decimal-to-hex-conversion-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @Magnus I don't think so - that was a follow up question from the same OP based on the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Convert INT to hex:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), 1234567891);
```

Convert hex to INT:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, 0x499602D3);
```

`BIGINT` should be the same deal replacing `INT` to `BIGINT` using

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), CAST(2716455883 as bigint));
```

See http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-convert-from-hex-to-int-and-back.html

Comment: the hex value of 2716455883 is A1E9D3CB but using SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), 2716455883) getting answer 0x0A000001CBD3E9A1

Comment: That is a Hexidecimal string. What you want is something else - but it is not standard hexidecimal. I will have a detailed look now...

Comment: @user1751909 `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), 1234567891);` gives me `0x499602D3` so I am not sure what is happening for you. To get the string you desire you will have to use `LTRIM()` on the returned string to get rid of the `0x`. But I confirm that what you are getting in your comment is indeed the correct hex for the INT you have. Who is telling you this is wrong and why?

Comment: @Killercam OP has already asked this question over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13643729/1220971) - it's resolved now.

Comment: @Bridge I am not sure why your comment is getting upvotes. This question was asked first and I answered what he wanted. He _then_ asked the question you reference in a comment to my answer. Sometimes, you spend time helping someone and get no thanks, which can be annoying - I am sure you have had this too! :] All the best and thanks for the heads up...

Comment: @Killercam I know, not very respectful of OP. Perhaps the upvotes are for me being helpful in telling you? As it turns out, the follow up question has also now got a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13644749/1220971