# decimal to hex conversion in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

the hex value of `2716455883` is `A1E9D3CB` but using

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), 2716455883)
```

getting answer `0x0A000001CBD3E9A1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), cast(2716455883 as bigint))
```

It is due to the way SQL Server interprets literals without qualified types. Check this out

```
select sql_variant_property(2716455883, 'basetype'); -- numeric
select sql_variant_property(2716455883, 'precision'); -- 10
select sql_variant_property(2716455883, 'scale'); -- 0
```

Comment: How is the `sql_variant_property` used in conjunction with the `CONVERT`?

Comment: @Killercam it's not. It's used to show the implicit type given to the number literal that falls outside the INT range