# Not getting correct answer while converting from hex to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the statements:

```
declare @x varchar(10)
declare @cardnum bigint
set @cardNum=9999999999
set @x=convert(varchar, CONVERT (varbinary(8), CONVERT(BIGINT, @cardNum)))
print @x
```

I an getting the answer as `Tãÿ` not getting Hex value `2540BE3FF` as string

Comment: You've not turned on the "magically guess what I mean when I string several conversion operations together" option. Without that, it's just going to dumbly apply each conversion as best it can.

Comment: @user1751909 Since you've asked several similar questions about this in the last few hours, why don't you actually tell us what you're trying to achieve? That way the community might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
declare @x varchar(50)
declare @cardnum bigint
set @cardNum=9999999999

declare @hexbin varbinary(max)
set @hexbin = CONVERT (varbinary(8), @cardNum)

Set @x = CONVERT(varchar(max), @hexbin, 1)
print @x

Set @x = CONVERT(varchar(max), @hexbin, 2)
print @x
```

Read more about it on this **[MSDN link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx)**